# why we get output as 'infinity' after the range of float is exceeded

Tags: java, memory, type-conversion

I am trying to figure out, when value of float exceed's the range i.e. greater than 3.4E38 it gives the output as 'infinity'. I understand that when float holds max_value all the bits in exponent bit will be holding '1' i.e. 11111111 and as soon as it exceeds the range it becomes 100000000 but Exponent bit can only hold 8 bit so '1' will be trucated and only '00000000' will be stored in the exponent block which is equal to 0. So, how output screen prints 'infinity'?

'''

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        float f=(float)3.4E+76;
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

'''

[output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiCRi.png)

Answer (score 2):

Infinity (including positive and negative infinity) is a [special value in floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Infinities) as defined in the floating-point standard [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Certain operations produce the value infinity, [including overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Dealing_with_exceptional_cases), and it is appropriately formatted as a string.

As described in the [rationale section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754_design_rationale):

> The special values such as infinity and NaN ensure that the floating-point arithmetic is algebraically complete: every floating-point operation produces a well-defined result and will not—by default—throw a machine interrupt or trap. Moreover, the choices of special values returned in exceptional cases were designed to give the correct answer in many cases. For instance, under IEEE 754 arithmetic, continued fractions such as R(z) := 7 − 3/[z − 2 − 1/(z − 7 + 10/[z − 2 − 2/(z − 3)])] will give the correct answer on all inputs, as the potential divide by zero, e.g. for z = 3, is correctly handled by giving +infinity, and so such exceptions can be safely ignored. As noted by Kahan, the unhandled trap consecutive to a floating-point to 16-bit integer conversion overflow that caused the loss of an Ariane 5 rocket would not have happened under the default IEEE 754 floating-point policy.